# ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat on a Buffer

Tags: directx

On a RGBA Texture this works as expected. Each component of the `FLOAT[4]` argument gets casted to the corresponding component of the `DXGI_FORMAT` of the texture.

However, with a Buffer this doesn't work and some rubbish is assigned the buffer based on the first component of the `FLOAT[4]` argument.

Although, this makes sense since a buffer UAV has no `DXGI_FORMAT` to specify what cast happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs said

> If you want to clear the UAV to a specific bit pattern, consider using ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint.

so you can just use as follows:

```cpp
float fill_value = ...;
auto Values = std::array<UINT, 4>{ *((UINT*)&fill_value),0,0,0};
commandList->ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint(
  ViewGPUHandleInCurrentHeap,
  ViewCPUHandle,
  pResource,
  Values.data(),
  0,
  nullptr
);
```

I believe the debug layer should raise a error when using `ClearUnorderedAccessViewFloat` on a Buffer.

**Edit**: it actually does I just missed it.

> D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12CommandList::ClearUnorderedAccessViewUint: ClearUnorderedAccessView* methods are not compatible with Structured Buffers. StructuredByteStride is set to 4 for resource 0x0000023899A09A40'. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #1156: CLEARUNORDEREDACCESSVIEW_INCOMPATIBLE_WITH_STRUCTURED_BUFFERS]